# Protoc variable consistent

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

Just to be clear: I am quite an amateur in C++ coding.

Presently, I am using Protobuff to serialize and exchange data between a c++ and a java model. Since both the models use different variables name for the same scientific terminology (for daily river drainage, c++  model uses dailyRiverDrianage and java uses dailyRdrainage). I used a new variable in protoc to define a variable being share.

My question is which is the best way to link both(protoc variable and model variable). Can't change the variable name in Java or C++

Comment: The correct variable name for Java according to the Java coding conventions is `dailyRiverDrainage`, not `d_r_drainage`. You should fix the source of the problem and rename the variable.

Comment: I am looking to link between the to types of variables. I have done the change in question. I am looking for an optimal way to link both protobuff variable as well as c++ and java variables without changing respective models variable names

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need an intermediate layer on one side to have a consistent mapping to the proto files. Do it on the Java side since you are more comfortable in that language. That intermediate layer would map from what ever is on the Java to the Java variables with different names.

Edit:

C++ side

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

Java Side

```
message Individual {
  required string fullName = 1;
  required int32 personal_id = 2;
  optional string personal_email = 3;
}
```

Send the data to the from C++ side to Java side. Generate the same Person message unit on Java side and deserialize the message get the data out and copy (map).

```
name -> fullName
id -> personal_id
email -> personal_email
```

This is then your decoder/converter unit that you can tinker around as the interfaces change.

Comment: hi mark, I understand the concept but cannot figure out away to do it, can you please share some examples or links where I can look for examples. (in c++ or java any language is helpful)